# XCode Location selector for simulator is disable?

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, ios-simulator

I want to simulate location in iPhone Simulator but the bar which shows option is disable. I am unable to find from where I can activate it?
Following is image

[image]

I also verified option in EditScheme, like this I checked it.

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It should be enabled as soon as you run your app

Answer (score 0):

XCode Location selector only enable when you run the app.

Comment: I run it on simulator, but yet same thing Sir

Comment: only No Selection option gets dark when I run it but nothing else, no click option is working on these button, no response when I click it.

Comment: No Selection option change as your project name after execute your code otherwise it shows No Selection

Comment: Its not changing name, I also see the Scheme, its okay from there, ALLOW LOCATION SIMULATION is checked. but still it doesn't show me any location option or dropdown

Comment: Yes, Its working fine. I can get location and do changes, use map, everything is fine Sir